# Formatting returned rails data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm very new to rails, but have a nice project going

I have the following in my model :

def self.get_feeds

```
sponsorlinks = RssFeed.all

links = sponsorlinks.each do |sponsorlink|
  puts sponsorlink.rss_url
end

feed_urls = ["link1","link2"]
update_from_feeds(feed_urls)
```

end

"links" outputs my 2 links to the console as expected but how do I get my two links into feed_urls = ["link1","link2"]

in the expected format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sponsorlinks = RssFeed.all

links = []
sponsorlinks.each do |sponsorlink|
  links << sponsorlink.rss_url
end
update_from_feeds(links)
```